# Beginner's Query: strange behaviour in string

Tags: c, arrays, string, getchar

There's probably a simple explanation to the problem I'm facing right now, although it'd be great if anyone helps with the solution. I am trying to learn arrays & strings & every time I enter a string by getchar() and try to output the same using scanf() in the program below, I sometimes get some strange characters in the output. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 100

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char array_str[N], c;

    printf("Enter the string array.\n");
    while ((c=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        array_str[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    array_str[i]='\n';
    printf(" the array_str is : %s\n",array_str);
    /* To output the string element wise  */
    i=0;
    while (array_str[i]!='\n')
    {
        printf("array_str[%d] is : %c\n", i, array_str[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a strange behaviour in the output. If I enter, say: "What is your name?", I get:

```
Enter the string array.
What is your name?
 the array_str is : What is your name?
"vjX"v:┘28
array_str[0] is : W
array_str[1] is : h
array_str[2] is : a
array_str[3] is : t
array_str[4] is :
array_str[5] is : i
array_str[6] is : s
array_str[7] is :
array_str[8] is : y
array_str[9] is : o
array_str[10] is : u
array_str[11] is : r
array_str[12] is :
array_str[13] is : n
array_str[14] is : a
array_str[15] is : m
array_str[16] is : e
array_str[17] is : ?

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.797 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Notice the garbled characters: **"vjX"v:┘28**. Similarly I keep getting other such types if I try say,

```
"Mary had  a li'l lamb." or, "Enter the Dragon."
```

But if I try:

```
"Hello World!" or "Good to know."
```

There are no such characters in the output. Why is this happening sometimes? Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. But why did the new-line character throw up different set of garbled characters in certain cases and not in some others?

Comment: See my full answer below. In short the garbage is whatever was in the memory when you declared the array.

Answer (score 2):

Literal arrays in c, when used as strings (see Blue Moon comment below), are `\0` terminated.

When you declared `array_str[N]` you allocated `N` characters for it (including space the zero termination). This allocation keeps the garbage that was in that memory location.

When you finished loading your `array_str` you "terminate" it by setting `array_str[i]='\n';`. This just adds a new line and hence your garbage goes to the following line in your output.

If you replace `\n` by `\0` you should get what you want.

Comment: Specifically, "%s" formatting expects a null-terminated string

Comment: The `for` loop expects a newline in the array. So replacing `\n` with `\0` is not going to work either. `Literal arrays in c are \0 terminated.` is not true -- null termination is only required if the array is used as a *string* like calling string functions on it or printing with `%s` as done by OP, etc. Otherwise, it's perfectly fine to *not* have the null terminator.

Comment: @blue-moon I agree that there is some liberty in my `\0` termination expectation. But, in practical terms, a chain of characters is generally expected to act as a string. As for the loop, it can check for `\0` instead of `\n` and all is well.

Comment: I agree. But your answer gives the impression that null termination is always necessary (at least to my reading), which is why I added a comment.

Comment: @blue-moon Fair enough, I edited my answer, to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't use `%s` format specifier unless it's terminated by null character. So the problem is with this line:

```
printf(" the array_str is : %s\n",array_str);
```

This leads to *[undefined behaviour.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* 
But in the later loop, you are checking for `\n` as the loop condition. That means, you need both `\n` and `\0` in your array:

```
array_str[i]='\n'; // For your for loop
array_str[i+1]='\0'; // So that you can print with %s
```

2) Your loop condition should be:

```
while (i<(N-2) && (c=getchar())!='\n')
```

so that you don't overflow the array and have 2 bytes for the `\n` and `\0`.

3) `getchar()` returns an `int`. So the type of `c` should be `int`. So that it can handle `EOF`.